# Comparing Basic Strings Exponential Complexity

Tags: vba, structure

I may be asking a silly question but I am self teaching myself VBA and I am just stumped and I am not even sure what terms I can use to look up a solution.

I am writing a code that will compare three variables to three other variables then I want to display which variables have changed.

So if x = a but y <> b and z <> c then the output should be b/c

I have worked out a code that works fine

```
    Dim Str As String
    If X <> A Then
        If Y <> B Then
            If Z <> C Then
                Str = "a/b/c"
            Else
                Str = "a/b"
            End If
        ElseIf Z <> C Then
            Str = "a/c"
        Else
            Str = "a"
        End If
    ElseIf Y <> B Then
            If Z <> C Then
                Str = "b/c"
            Else
                Str = "b"
            End If
    Else
        Str = "c"
    End If
```

But as I increase the number of variables this becomes extremely complex very quickly.

If anyone can help direct me to a simpler method without the exponential complexity I would be very grateful.

Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 3):

You need to test each variable pair independently from each other -- not link them together in one giant `If` construct tree.

Example:

```
str = "" 'Start with blank string. Append as required.
If x <> a Then str = str & "a/"
If y <> b Then str = str & "b/"
If z <> c Then str = str & "c/"

'Remove the extra / at the end
If Right(str, 1) = "/" Then str = Left(str, Len(str - 1))
```

Answer (score -1):

You could put the 2 strings in 2 arrays, and then use a `FOR...NEXT` construct to loop both arrays. You can use `UBound(arValues)` to dynamically find out the number of items in the array.
Good luck